# Table of button (for example 8x8) in Android

Tags: android, layout, button

How can I make a `Layout` with `Buttons` in matrix like:

`Button` `Button`

`Button` `Button`

I want to have access to these `Buttons` by the loop (for example, `for()`), because I want to change the text of these `Buttons` dynamically.

I tried to make a `TableLayout` and `TableRow`, but nothing works.

Comment: Can you post the code you tried, because it should be possible with a TableLayout?

Comment: @user1055201 check my answer, i used tablelayout and it worked very well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use TableLayout.

Check here for explanation:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html

Here an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout">

<TableLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableLayout1">
    <TableRow 
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <Button
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:id="@+id/button1" 
             android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
             android:text="@string/first_color">
        </Button>
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/button2" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/second_color">
        </Button>
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/button3" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:text="@string/third_color" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </Button>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow 
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/button5" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="@string/tolerance">
        </Button>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</LinearLayou>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:src="@drawable/i1"
        android:id="@+id/imgview11"
        android:layout_width="88dp"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgview12"
        android:src="@drawable/i2"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    </ImageView>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgview13"
        android:src="@drawable/i3"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
    </ImageView>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgview21"
        android:src="@drawable/i4"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgview11"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imgview11">
    </ImageView>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgview22"
        android:src="@drawable/i5"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgview12"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgview12">
    </ImageView>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgview23"
        android:src="@drawable/i6"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgview12"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgview13">
    </ImageView>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgview31"
        android:src="@drawable/i7"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgview22">
    </ImageView>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgview32"
        android:src="@drawable/i8"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgview21"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgview12">
    </ImageView>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgview33"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgview22"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
    </ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am using ImageView's here. You can change to Button instead of ImageView.